# Why is optimal transport theory so relevant?

Tags: intuition, linear-pde, optimal-transport

I see plenty of papers published with "optimal transport" in their title and I know that at least 2 Fields medal in the last 10 years were assigned for something related to optimal transport theory. So, why is it so foundamental?

To me it seems a rather straightforward PDE and nothing more. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you read wikipedia's article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)#Motivation ? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: That those are applications not really a motivation to study the field. For example, I know that transport equation could be related to the evolution of the weights of a neural network, but that doesn't mean it is "meaningful" per-se. What I'm looking for is a motivation to study the theory itself, what are the missing pieces everyone is after and where is the beauty of it.

Comment: 'To me it seems a rather straightforward PDE and nothing more.' If you think 'optimal transport' is the theory of the transport equation, then basically you are missing everything.

Comment: and that's why I am asking what am I missing. Because if it is so relevant in nowadays research surely I'm missing the point :)

Comment: I cannot give an introduction to OT in a post. Maybe you should first revise the wiki article mentioned. Because in fact the article is not in the first place about applications, but rather motivations. OT started with economic problems of optimal allocation of goods, and eventually led via the Monge-problem to its relaxation the Monge-Kantorovich problem which is basically the central object in OT theory. OT theory allows for many fruitful interactions in particluar between probability theory, PDEs and geometry. Certainly one of the reasons for its success.